# How to create a groovy function with stage and steps

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile with a pipeline call that become longer and longer and I would like to create function from it to have better readability.

See the Jenkinsfile :

```
def utils

def setupEnvironment() {
    def localUtils

     SVN Export for cm/jenkins
    pwsh """
        svn export --username=\"\$env:ARTIFACTORY_CREDS_USR\" --password=\"\$env:ARTIFACTORY_CREDS_PSW\" -q ${UTILS_SVN_PATH} cm/jenkins
    """    

     Load utils.groovy
    echo "Loading utils.groovy from ${WORKSPACE}/cm/jenkins/utils.groovy"
    localUtils = load("${WORKSPACE}/cm/jenkins/utils.groovy")
    
     Check if utils is loaded successfully
    if (localUtils == null) {
        error "Failed to load utils.groovy"
    } else {
        echo "utils.groovy loaded successfully."
    }

    return localUtils
}


pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    environment {
        List of env variables to set from jenkins server
    }

    stages {   
        stage('Setup') {
            agent { label 'linux-docker' }
            steps {
                script {
                    utils = setupEnvironment()
                }
            }
        }

        stage('main') {
            parallel {
                stage('Windows') {
                     agent {label 'windows-docker'}
                     environment {
                         WINDOWS_EXPORT_DIR = "voice_windows-${env.CURRENT_DATE_TIME}"   New environment variable
                     }                    
                     stages {
                         stage('Windows svn'){
                             steps{
                                 script{
                                     echo "The Windows svn export Node Name is: ${NODE_NAME}"
                                     utils.svnExport(FX_SVN_PATH, WINDOWS_EXPORT_DIR)
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                         stage('Windows docker') {
                             steps {
                                 pwsh """
                                     docker image prune -f
                                 """
                                 script {
                                     echo "The Windows docker image Node Name is: ${NODE_NAME}"
                                     env.DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG_FOR_VOICE = utils.processDockerImage(WINDOWS_EXPORT_DIR,
                                                                                         WINDOWS_VOICE_DOCKERFILE, 
                                                                                         WINDOWS_IMAGE_NAME, 
                                                                                         FX_SVN_PATH, 
                                                                                         FX_DOCKERFILES_SVN_PATH)
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                         stage('Windows Build') {
                             steps {
                                  Your build steps go here.
                                 script {
                                     utils.buildWindowsVoice(WINDOWS_EXPORT_DIR, WINDOWS_IMAGE_NAME, env.DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG_FOR_VOICE)
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     post {
                         always {
                             cleanWs()
                         }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the file above, I would like to create a function from the stage `stage('Windows')`.  So, I will have something like this :

```
        stage('main') {
            parallel {
                buildWindows()
            }
         }
```

I tried to move the code in a groovy function, but I got an error saying `steps` is not recognized.  I think it is because I mixed scripted and declarative syntax.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is that you are using scripts in a declarative pipeline. If you were to use a script pipeline, it would be easy to move whatever you want into a method.

Answer (score 0):

For better readability you should define functions inside Jenkins shared libraries and include them in your Jenkinsfile with the annotation @Library('my-shared-library') _

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: Why is it for better readability? And how to support it then? I think if a method is part of a pipeline it shouldn't be moved to a library.